Does $|X_n|+|Y_n|=o_p\left(1\right)$ imply $|X_n|=o_p\left(1\right)$?
$X_n$ and $Y_n$ are random variables. In this slides, I learned the properties of $o_p$, such as $o_p(1)+o_p(1)=o_p(1)$ (on page 5). Intuitively, if $|X_n|+|Y_n|=o_p(1)$ hold, we have $|X_n|=o_p(1)$. Is this correct? How to prove it?

It is correct.
$|X_n|+|Y_n|\geq |X_n|$, so for any $M$ and $\epsilon$,
$|X_n|+|Y_n|<M$ implies $|X_n|<M$ and so
$$P(|X_n|+|Y_n|<M)>1-\epsilon$$ implies
$$P(|X_n|<M)>1-\epsilon$$
which is what you're trying to prove.
